# Open a console in the wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, console, .net-5

I was trying to go acording to this tutorial: https://ikriv.com/blog/?p=2470. So You create a WPF app and program.cs with this code:

```cs
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new App();

        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
    }
}
```

Then just change the Startup and Output type.

However, this solution appears to break in the new .NET 5.0 while it works fine in .NET Framework.Is there a way to do this similarly easy in the new version? Thank you very much.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/14503

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/5.0/automatically-infer-winexe-output-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Robert Harvey solves the question. I used this tutorial (https://ikriv.com/blog/?p=2470) and for a .NET 5.0 I followed this:(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/automatically-infer-winexe-output-type)

You can not accept a comment, so I hope it does not matter if I write the summary like this.

Answer (score 1):

@ Naman Kumar.

For opening Console application you could manually open Console window in WPF application( .NET 5.0). You can add the **AllocConsole** and **FreeConsole** methods to your class and use it as shown below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32")]
        public static extern void AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("Kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern void FreeConsole();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OutputTextBox.Focus();
            AllocConsole();
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var line = OutputTextBox.Text;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(line);
        }
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FreeConsole();
        }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, @Filip Z. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.